# How to force user to take image via camera ( intent camera) or how to disable intent camera back button?

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I want to force user to click image once camera opened, he should not go back without clicking image via back button.

Please suggest me how to implement force click or disable intent camera back button in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible, sorry. If you need that degree of control over the camera, do not use an `Intent` to launch some third-party camera app. You will need to write your own camera logic, using the camera APIs or a library wrapper around them (CameraX, Fotoapparat, CameraKit/Android, etc.).